# Syntax Error on mysql php load data infile

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

This is my first time trying to import data from csv file into mysql table.

The problem is that the order of csv columns doesn't match the order in table and also there is one column (auto increment) `id` missing from csv. I am trying to do this but it gives me syntax error.

```
        $sql="LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' 
 INTO TABLE calls 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ".'"'." 
 (`account_code`,`source`,`destination`,`dbcontext`,`caller_id`,`channel`,`destination-channel`,`lastapp`,`lastdata`,`start`,`answer`,`end`,`duration`,`billseconds`,`disposition`,`amaflag`,`call_id`,`userfield`)";
```

Notice the `$file` is the file name dynamically generated. I get this error upon execution of the query.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY " (`account_code`,`source`,`destination`,`dbcontext`,`' at line 4
```

Any idea why?

Thanks 
Ahmar

Comment: Shouldn't the enclosed by clause have two quote characters? Looks you've only got one

Comment: @Clive just tried with two and still the same error

Comment: By the way, you can replace `".'"'."` with just `\"`

Comment: I did that also still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "
```

Needs to be

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

So your code should change to

```
$sql="LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' 
 INTO TABLE calls 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 

 (`account_code`,`source`,`destination`,`dbcontext`,`caller_id`,`channel`,`destination-channel`,`lastapp`,`lastdata`,`start`,`answer`,`end`,`duration`,`billseconds`,`disposition`,`amaflag`,`call_id`,`userfield`)";
```

(adding the required single quotes and swapping the order of clauses is all that's changed, but I also changed your concatenation to something a bit more readable).

Comment: Try the edit, you had things slightly the wrong way round (`ENCLOSED BY` refers to the fields, not the lines). That query no longer gives me a syntax error so you should be good to go

Comment: By the way on my local server I am giving the script an absolute path like this C:\wamp\tmp\php790E.tmp but it automatically goes to bin folder and gives me this error c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\wamp mpphp790E.tmp' not found (Errcode: 22 - Invalid argument)  Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't - I use *nix and always use an absolute path (/path/to/file); I haven't run into that problem before, but it seems like your path is being interpreted as a relative one